# Tkinter save and print entry string on button click

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a weather station program for my school project and I need some help. How can I store one value that users will input and then change currently pre-set value to "Inputted" value?

```
import tkinter

from tkinter import *

def test():
    city.config(text="test")

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather Station")


root.geometry("400x350")

city = Label(root, text="City", pady=20,font="Arial 12")
city.pack()


button1 = Button(root, text="Check",command=test).place(x=150,y=313)
city_name = StringVar()
entry_box = Entry(root, textvariable=city_name).place(x=10,y=315)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: to save your data you need a database or file,

Comment: `entry_box = Entry().place()` will assign `None` to `entry_box` because `place()`/`pack()`/`grid()` returns `None` . If you don't use `entry_box` in other part of code then you can skip `entry_box = `. If you use `entry_box` in other part of code then you have to do it in two steps `entry_box = Entry(...)` and `entry_box.place()`. The same with `button1 = Button().pack()`

Comment: when you say `store` do you means keep it when you close program and run it again? Then you will have to save it in file or database, and read it at start. You can use plain text file, json file, yalm file, pickle file, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I think your problem is with the function named test. I renamed it to mytest.

```
from tkinter import *

def mytest():
    city.config(text=city_name.get())

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather Station")


root.geometry("400x350")

city = Label(root, text="City", pady=20,font="Arial 12")
city.pack()


button1 = Button(root, text="Check", command=mytest).place(x=150,y=313)
city_name = StringVar()
entry_box = Entry(root, textvariable=city_name).place(x=10,y=315)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That code does same thing that I posted up there, but thanks for posting.
I need to know how to store a string that will be writen in text box and then print it on a city Label

Comment: Ah okay, I update the code try that. You just needed to get the value from the StringVar()